# How to skip an NA column in a rolling window in R

Tags: r, na, rolling-computation

Imagine the data:

```
>dput(mydata)
structure(c(9.3424, 9.3424, 9.3983, 9.5102, 9.3144, 9.4822, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.8478, 8.1167, 7.6421, 7.4048, 5.3479, 5.3004, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13.4319, 13.6184, 13.805, 13.8983, 13.8983, 
13.805), .Dim = c(6L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5")))
```

What I am trying to do is apply an algorithm in a Rolling window, what the algorithm does is running a sampling methodology and then produces some summary stats for each column separately. The columns do not interact with each other in any way. The problem is that there are NAs in the data. What I want to happen is that when the rolling window is full of NAs I want the rolling window to skip that column and in the summary stats put an NA value.

EXAMPLE:

```
mydata<-sp.val[,c(1:5)]
summarrry<-matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=2)
roller<-5
for (u in 1:roller){
  for (j in 1:5){ #50 is the assets consider using 498
  testdata<-mydata[(u:(u+365)),] 
  lin<-lm(testdata[,1]~testdata[,j],data=as.data.frame(testdata))
  summarrry[j,]<-coef(lin)
  print(summarrry)
  }
}
```

This returns the error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

which is due to the NA columns.

Thus I want to skip the columns of the rolling window that are: either full of NA (`length(which.na(data))==window`) or have one one numeric value (`length(which.na(data))==(window-1)`).

Desired Output: 
Running the above returns this:
Column 1 is the intercept and 2 is the coef.

```
        [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 2.971253e-15    1
[2,] 0.000000e+00    0
[3,] 0.000000e+00    0
[4,] 0.000000e+00    0
[5,] 0.000000e+00    0
```

and it stops due to the error mentioned because of the NA.
What I want to happen:

```
         [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 2.971253e-15    1
[2,] NA              NA
[3,] 2.455878        1.841197
[4,] NA              NA
[5,] 2.5868          0.5759558
```

Comment: `zoo::rollapply` ?

Comment: I am quite unfamiliar with the `zoo` package. Also I am trying to do this without a package if possible. Does `rollapply` allow me to skip a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code is not reproducible (comes up with an out of bounds error because of the u+365). However, why not just add an `if` statement there?

```
summarrry<-matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=2)
roller<-5
for (u in 1:roller){
    for (j in 1:5){ #50 is the assets consider using 498
        testdata<-mydata[(u:(u+365)),] 
 # check if there are any non-NAs in the column and then calculate the lm:
        if(any(!is.na(testdata[,j]))) lin<-lm(testdata[,1]~testdata[,j],data=as.data.frame(testdata)) else lin<-NA
        summarrry[j,]<-if (!is.na(lin)) coef(lin) else c(NA,NA)
        print(summarrry)
    }
}
```

(To be honest I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve - the `{}` may or may not be necessary)

Comment: Applogies, i mistakenly didnt reduce the u in the example. What i am trying to achieve is basically a huge bayesian rolling window analysis. And that is the only issue i have so far. Will test it and let you know.

Comment: Made some revisions to the code to introduce NAs to the resulting array